# Git mirror of non-LFS repo to LFS-repo

Tags: git, mirror, git-lfs

I'm looking to set up a mirror of a non-LFS repo on GitHub that limits me to LFS for larger than 100 MB files.
There is no alternative to using GitHub.

My approach:

```
git clone --bare <REPO>
git lfs migrate import --include="*.zip" --everything
git push <MIRROR> --set-upstream --all
```

The problem I see is that in case the original repository has new commit and the mirror has the rewritten LFS commit, how will an update take place?
I tried various methods but nothing so far made too much sense to me.

Has anyone encountered this and how did you resolve this?

Comment: Why can you not use LFS for the original repo as well?

Comment: Because it's not owned by me.

Comment: Well, then I guess the person who does own it is going to have to make a choice, because there is no "this clone uses LFS but this one doesn't".

Comment: I have literally 0 influence over the other repository, hence my question.